# How to search for users in WP with serialized meta values

Tags: wordpress

I can get users using `$all_users = get_users(['meta_key' => 'first_name', 'meta_value' => 'john']);` but I have a small problem now, as the meta value for feature I am trying to fetch is serialized.

I have copied a row from the table as shown below.

```
103  wp_capabilities       a:1:{s:12:"cs_candidate";b:1;}
```

I can get the value and unserialize it, but not sure if there is a way to do this in WP.

#### UPDATE:

To add more clarification, I am referring to this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users or the below function to be exact:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
    'role'         => '',
    'role__in'     => array(),
    'role__not_in' => array(),
    'meta_key'     => '',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '',
    'meta_query'   => array(),
    'date_query'   => array(),        
    'include'      => array(),
    'exclude'      => array(),
    'orderby'      => 'login',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'offset'       => '',
    'search'       => '',
    'number'       => '',
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'all',
    'who'          => ''
 ); 
get_users( $args ); ?>
```

The `'meta_value'   => '',` part in the field is serialized `a:1:{s:12:"cs_candidate";b:1;}`

Comment: It is not immediately clear what you are asking. You want to use `get_users`, but search by a serialized `meta_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't search unserialize an search at the same time, I'm afraid. Searching in serialized data is always a bit of a hassle.

If you are certain of structure of the data you are searching, you could do something like:

```
$meta_args = [
        'key'     => 'wp_capabilities',
        'value'   => 'cs_candidate";b:1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];

$users = get_users(['meta_query' => $meta_args]);
```

It's anything but pretty, but should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, this requires me to know the structure beforehand. But this is my first time using wp and I am not sure if the value will change from time to time. but for now, I will wait for any better alternative

Comment: The structure doesn't depend much on WP, but on php's native function "serialize". So the structure should hold. Since you are searching for serialized data in mysql, and you can't treat serialized fields as something else than text, you won't have many other options than go this way.